# Wordpress plugin stats

Tags: wordpress, plugins, statistics

I have released a wordpress plugin recently and I wonder if there is a way to see how many people actually use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tab called "stats" in the plugin directory that shows you how many that has downloaded you plugin, but you can't see anywhere how many that has the plugin installed right now, unless you code it so that it "calls home" on activation. Which is a bad idea in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

What some developers do is add a ping-back or include a 1 pixel gif file with full url to the developers website. Then when the plugin is used you can track the websites that load your gif file. This is not appreciated by people and is a bad idea in my opinion, but it is something you can do to track things. You can even go a step further and add JS of analytics software. But please be aware that the community will not like this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are basic stats of Wordpress.org

https://wordpress.org/plugins/YOUR-PLUGIN-SLUG/advanced/

for more stats, you can create functional when someone activate/deactivate your plugin (send requests to your own server via custom API) or smth like that